# How to export attribute tables to Excel?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, export

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I export an attribute table in ArcGIS version 9.3.1 to Excel?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28308/how-do-i-export-an-attribute-table-in-arcgis-version-9-3-1-to-excel)

We are running 10.0 and are trying to simply export an attribute table to Excel other than exporting to dbf and opening straight away in excel.

The problem is our GIS Manager does not trust everything that is exported as far as formatting etc..changed info from database to excel.

In other words..when we view the attribute table they want the same identical view in excel!

Comment: I suspect your GIS manager has no problem reading dbf files in excel as a terminal process, although does not want to see spatial data edited in excel and brought back into ArcGIS.

Comment: I am not realy sure what is the eact problem, but csv format is much faster than the dbf format.

Comment: There are many questions of this kind on this site already, example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28308/how-do-i-export-an-attribute-table-in-arcgis-version-9-3-1-to-excel

Answer (score 9):

You can select all records in the attribute table using the grab handle (left most column) and by holding the Shift key (then choose 'Copy Selected'). Then simply open Excel and paste the values.

This is much quicker than exporting to .dbf (unless of course you need to edit the attribute table data, in which case, it's preferable to do this in ArcMap using the Field Calculator and/or Editor utilities).

Comment: There is no 'Copy Selected' in 10.2.2, what other options are there?

Comment: There certainly is in my version (also 10.2.2, version 3552), are you sure that you're looking in the attribute table?

Comment: right click on grab handle (left most column) opens the dialog too

Answer (score 5):

One of the table export options is Text, which is really in CSV format, so it can be easily opened in Excel without concern of truncated field names (and other DBF issues).

Alternately, there is an [add-on that allows export to Excel](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/35206-ArcGIS-10-export-to-Excel).

Answer (score 5):

The [Xtools Pro](http://www.dataeast.com/en/XToolspro.asp) extension will do this, it will also let you choose the fields you want to include in the export, which can make things go faster if you have a table with dozens of fields and you only need a few of them. It's a paid extension but only some of its features require paid registration, most of them (including the Export to Excel one) are free to use indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

These tools (which work in 10/10.1) convert to Excel.
[Download from ArcGIS.com](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f3d91b8f852042e289e09a7ec8342431)