# Export coded value domains

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, domains, error-999999

I've attempted to write a script that will export all the coded value domains in a geodatabase to a table. Before I dig in the to script and what's wrong, I have looked at the similar [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26215/export-all-coded-value-domains-from-a-geodatabase) on this topic, but that script would not run for me. Here is my code:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"F:\ITree"
gdb = r"ITree.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(gdb)

for domain in domains:
     if domain.domainType == 'CodedValue':
         domain_name = domain.name
         print 'Exporting {0} coded values to table in {1}'.format(domain_name, gdb)
         coded_value_list = domain.codedValues
         print "The coded values / descriptions are"
         for value, descrip in coded_value_list.iteritems():
             print "{0} : {1}".format(value, descrip)
         out_table_name = domain_name.lower()
         #arcpy.DomainToTable_management(gdb, domain_name, out_table_name, "item", "descrip")
     else:
         print "{0} not a coded value domain. Passing it up.".format(domain.name)
```

When I comment out the Domain to Table, the script runs and produces, this:

```
Exporting LANDUSE coded values to table in ITree.gdb
The coded values / descriptions are
1 : Single family residential
0 : Not entered
3 : Small commercial
2 : Multi-family residential
5 : Park/vacant/other
4 : Industrial/Large commercial
```

However, when I uncomment the Domain to Table, it produces the following error:

```
Exporting LANDUSE coded values to table in ITree.gdb
The coded values / descriptions are
1 : Single family residential
0 : Not entered
3 : Small commercial
2 : Multi-family residential
5 : Park/vacant/other
4 : Industrial/Large commercial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Work/MDC/GISData/MOTools/Scripts/export_gdb_domains.py", line 29, in <module>
    arcpy.DomainToTable_management(gdb, domain_name, out_table_name, "item", "descrip")
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 1491, in DomainToTable
    raise e
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Failed to execute (DomainToTable).
```

It also produces the first table from the domain, but does not copy the coded values and creates an empty table. I've looked through the help documents for [Domain to Table (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000022000000) and [List Domains](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w0000001z000000), but I cannot figure out why it's throwing an error. Clearly something is off in the Domain to Table function, but I can't figure out what, especially since it prints all the parameters correctly.

Using ArcGIS 10.3 and PyCharm Community 4.0.5 with Python 2.7.9

Comment: Are you running this from command line or in the Python shell in ArcMap?  The first parameter in the domaintotable_management, try setting it to the full directory path r"F:\ITree.gdb".  The 99999 errors are a pain and very arbitrary.  If you are running from command line, I've seen issues on certain machines where you set the enviornment and workspace, and then some how they get changed.

Comment: I'm running it in PyCharm. I changed the gdb variable to the full path: F:\ITree\ITree.gdb and got the same error.

Comment: I agree with @branchini that this is almost certainly due to the way that you are using `arcpy.env.workspace` in conjunction with a `gdb` variable.  I would set `arcpy.env.workspace = r"F:\ITree.gdb"` and dispense with using the `gdb` variable because you can recall that using `arcpy.env.workspace` instead.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo. That did the trick. I'll post the amended code as an answer. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @branchini and @PolyGeo for the advice. Below is the amended code. I changed the workspace to the full path of the geodatabase and changed the gdb variable to the workspace.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"F:\ITree\ITree.gdb"
gdb = arcpy.env.workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(gdb)

for domain in domains:
     if domain.domainType == 'CodedValue':
         domain_name = domain.name
         print 'Exporting {0} coded values to table in {1}'.format(domain_name, gdb)
         coded_value_list = domain.codedValues
         print "The coded values / descriptions are"
         for value, descrip in coded_value_list.iteritems():
             print "{0} : {1}".format(value, descrip)
         out_table_name = domain_name.lower()
         arcpy.DomainToTable_management(gdb, domain_name, out_table_name, "item", "descrip")
     else:
         print "{0} not a coded value domain. Passing it up.".format(domain.name)
```