# Using arcpy.Exists for domains?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, domains

A script I made creates domains within a selected geodatabase.

I need it to not create the domains if they already exist because if they do, it gives an error saying invalid domain name.

What's the best way to check if a domain exists?

Comment: See this post, might help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25129/how-to-check-if-domain-already-exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

arcpy.Exists doesn't handle domains. The ESRI help [indicates what it does handle](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000021000000).

So you'll need to get a list of existing domains, and then check your potential new name against the list. What version of ArcGIS are you using? **10.1** introduces a new `ListDomains` function.

If you're on ArcGIS **10.0**, then you don't have this `ListDomains`. In that case I think you should go with the answer to [How to check if domain already exists?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25129/how-to-check-if-domain-already-exists), which describes how to use the workspace `Describe` function to check for existence.

If you're on ArcGIS **10.1**, then you can try out the new `ListDomains` function (data access module) to get a list of existing domain names for a geodatabase, and then compare your potential new name to the list of existing names.

Something like this:

```
myNewDomains = ['new one', 'new two']
existingDomains = arcpy.da.ListDomains("C:/xyz/xyz.gdb")

for myNewDomain in myNewDomains:
    # check if myNewDomain already exists
    found = False
    for domain in existingDomains: 
        if domain.name == myNewDomain:
            found = True
            break
    # if myNewDomain doesn't already exist, then create it
    if found = False:
        #
        # drop in your domain-creation code
        #
    else:
        print "Domain already exists:", myNewDomain
```

Comment: @I-B: a gdb or workspace has domains, but it doesn't immediately have fields. It can have tables and those tables can have fields. I suggest searching this GIS SE site or ArcGIS help, and then maybe asking a new question here.  Try this: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/ListFields/000v0000001p000000/