# Printing Existing Domains

Tags: arcpy, domains

I currently am using the code below to create a List of existing Domains on a Geodatabase, and if there are none to create one. The code does create the domain, but is not creating the list of Domains if they already exist. Did I set up the if statement incorrectly or do I need another function to give me the list of current domains?

I have referenced the following question, [How to check if domain already exists?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25129/how-to-check-if-domain-already-exists) but the print function is not working for me.

```
domains=arcpy.da.ListDomains(outputGDB)
if len(domains) == 0:
    domName = 'DomStatus'
    arcpy.CreateDomain_management(r'X:\GIS_PROJECTS\City.gdb', domName, '', 'TEXT', 'CODED')
    arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management(r'X:\GIS_PROJECTS\City.gdb', domName, 1, 'Boundary Used')
    arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management(r'X:\GIS_PROJECTS\NATIONAL\ParkServe\Documentation\Test_HW\ParkScore_Loading\New_Mexico__Albuquerque.gdb', domName, 2, 'Added')
    arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management(r'X:\GIS_PROJECTS\City.gdb', domName, 3, 'Deleted')
    arcpy.AddField_management(newFC, 'Status_2017', 'TEXT',field_length=50, field_domain=domName)
    print "Domain Created"
else:
    print domains
```

Comment: What happens if you just do your first line and your last line - `domains=arcpy.da.ListDomains(outputGDB)` and then on the next line `print domains`?  It should print a number of domain objects although not specifying names.  If it's not then there may be something else not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ListDomains function returns a list of domain objects, which have a .name property.

To create a list of domain names, you have to call the name property of each domain object returned by the function. You should do something like this:

```
domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(outputGDB)
domainnames = []
for domain in domains:
    domainnames.append(domain.name)
print domainnames
```

This will append each domain's name property to a new list (domainnames) and print it

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a list of domain objects from the line `domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(outputGDB)`, so you will need to loop through that list and ask for the name of each domain:

```
domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(outputGDB)
if len(domains) == 0:
    ...
else:
    for d in domains:
        print d.name
```

If this is being run through ArcMap script tool rather than in a stand-alone python script you will need to use `arcpy.AddMessage()` rather than print

```
domains = arcpy.da.ListDomains(outputGDB)
if len(domains) == 0:
    ...
else:
    for d in domains:
        arcpy.AddMessage(d.name)
```

Comment: It still continues to run and not print the domains, even though there are 3 on the GDB.

Comment: @Purplepeopleeater You say in your question that it creates the domain - in that case it should never print any domain names, although it shouldn't be creating the domain if the `len(domains)` isn't `0`

Comment: I want to see if there are any domains associated with the GDB, checking the length to do that, so if there are 0 it will then create the one that I want and if there are existing domains to list them.  Am I structuring the if statement wrong then?

Comment: @Purplepeopleeater Are you running this from a script tool in ArcMap, or stand-alone python?

Comment: I am now running it as a script tool, and have set up parameters.

Comment: @Purplepeopleeater then replace `print d.name` with `arcpy.AddMessage(d.name)`

Comment: That did the trick! good to know!